# Materialize CSS in Sapper

Tags: materialize, svelte, rollupjs, sapper

I'm trying to set up a project in Sapper (with Svelte).

I want to use the Materialize CSS framework and JS components in my project.

How could I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i -D materialize-css` (and `npm i -D @types/materialize-css` if using typescript)

Then just add

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
...
M.AutoInit();
```

to `src/client.js`

and

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

to `src/template.html`

**EDIT:** If using typescript, add

```json
"compilerOptions": {"types": ["materialize-css", "svelte"]}
```

to `tsconfig.json`

[Original Reddit comment answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/j6ku7c/materialize_css_in_sapper/g8103p9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)